# Custom tag doesn't render template completely

Tags: django

so here's my custom tag:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('app/comments_list.html', takes_context=True)
def show_comments(context):
    request = context['request']  
    comments_list = Comments.objects.all().order_by('-comment_time')  
    paginator = Paginator(comments_list, 3) 
    page = request.GET.get('page')  
    try:
        comments = paginator.page(page)   
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        comments = paginator.page(1)  
    except EmptyPage:
        comments = paginator.page(
            paginator.num_pages)  
    return {'comments': comments}
```

and here's my template to render:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
{% if comment.commented_by.username == user.username %}
<h6><font color="green">You</font></h6>
{% else %}
{{comment.commented_by}}
<h7>{{ comment.comment_time }}</h7>
{% endif %}
<div class="comment">
    {{comment}}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

My model:

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    commented_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    comment_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

For some reason it successfully renders everything except for the
`if` condition. And I have no idea why.
Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What is request.GET` doing in `comments = paginator.page(page)   request.GET`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem just a typo i guess while I was posting a question. I've edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary you return from your function becomes the *context* for the template that is going to be rendered. Hence there is no variable `user` in the context in your template `app/comments_list.html`. You can change the dictionary you return to also pass the user:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('app/comments_list.html', takes_context=True)
def show_comments(context):
    ...
    return {'comments': comments, 'user': context['user']}
```

> **Note**: Generally business logic is performed in the *views*, and I don't assume many pages need you to get the comments? What you do by
> adding custom template tags for this would be somewhat frowned upon by
> Django developers, as this logic is better suited for the view.

Comment: Yeah, i've already  realized i forgot about adding user in context=\ sorry about silly question. I am just trying new things to learn Django really i am not pursuing any concept at this moment.